# How to tune move_base local planners for frequent goal updates

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experimenting with a robot which is supposed to follow a beacon outside. The waypoints are sent at 1Hz (I could go faster) and are within 3 to 10 meters of the robot. I tried using move_base with the built-in planners but had unsatisfactory results.

- DWA planner's motion was good but it made the robot pause at every goal update making for unsmooth motion
- TrajectoryPlannerRos starts oscillating on straightaways, that type of motion isn't acceptable
- TebLocalPlanner was a mix of the two, but it did a lot of spinning in place and eventually would cause the map update loop miss its target update rate

I tried to play with oscillation reset flag and other parameters but still did not achieve good results and to be honest, I'm not really sure how most of these work. I am starting to think that these planners weren't meant to be used for what I'm using them for. Is there a better planner for me to use such that I can update it frequently yet still get the benefit of obstacle following? If not, are there parameters I should be tuning that will make path updates faster and smoother? (local map size/resolution? oscillation flag? others?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266021/how-to-tune-move_base-local-planners-for-frequent-goal-updates/) by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 435 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is not with the planners, but with `move_base`.
Check this related question, with lots of info on the matter: [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/28950/what-is-the-best-way-to-follow-a-moving-target/)

ps.: this is a clone from the code from the second answer: https://github.com/awesomebytes/hist_user_tracking

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1